# Swift enum: "Extraneous '.' in enum 'case' declaration"

Tags: swift, enums, syntax, syntax-error

When working with Swift enums, you generally refer to each enumeration case using dot syntax. Commonly typing `.someName` or `case .someName`, but never just `someName`.

Now I've declared a new Swift enum like so, using the same syntax:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case .one
    case .two
}
```

but this enum gives the error:

> Extraneous '.' in enum 'case' declaration

Comment: The error message is very clear and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift enumeration cases are defined as `case someName`, not `case .someName`.

This is an easy syntax error when declaring a new enum's cases, as in most other situations you will be typing `.someName` via dot syntax. But when first declaring that enum case, it's `case someName` without the period.

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case one
    case two
    
    var otherCase: Self {
        switch self {
        case .one: return .two
        case .two: return .one
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course is how to declare an enumeration. Just read the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).